# Independence of Solution of SDE $S^{(x_0, \sigma, \mu)}_t$ of Initial Information $\mathcal{G}_0$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, independence, stochastic-differential-equations

**Question**

Consider the following stochastic differential equation, given as an equivalent stochastic integral equation, where the multidimensional integrals are to be read componentwise:

\begin{equation}
 S_t = x_0 + \int_{0}^{t} \mu(S_t) ds + \int_{0}^{t} \sigma (S_t) dB_s.
\end{equation}

Under our assumptions (see below), it is the case that an (up to indistinguishability) unique solution process

$$ S^{(x_0, \sigma, \mu)} :[0,T] \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d, \quad (t, \omega) \mapsto S_t(\omega),$$

for this equation exists (to see this, consider for example Theorem 8.3. in *Brownian Motion, Martingales and Stochastic Calculus* from Le Gall).

Now, I suspect, that, for all $t \in [0,T]$, the random variable $S^{(x_0, \sigma, \mu)}_t$ is **independent** of $\mathcal{G}_0$, which is the initial $\sigma$-algebra of the underlying filtration .

Is this true? How could I show this rigorously? It is trivial for the case $t = 0$, but what if $t >0$?

I suspect, the result follows somehow from the fact, that $(B_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ has independent increments.

I am stuck and I would be extremely grateful for any advice!

**Preliminaries and Standard Technical Framework**

- Let $T \in (0, \infty)$ be fixed.
- Let $d \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ be fixed.
- Let $$(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, (\mathcal{G}_t)_{t \in [0,T]},
     \mathbb{P})$$ be a complete probability space with a complete,
  right-continuous filtration $(\mathcal{G}_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$.
- Let $$B : [0,T] \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d, \quad
     (t,\omega) \mapsto B_t(\omega)$$ be a standard $d$-dimensional
  $(\mathcal{G}_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$-adapted Brownian motion on
  $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that, for every pair $(t,s) \in \mathbb{R}^2$
  with $0 \leq t < s$, the random variable $B_s-B_t$ is independent of
  $\mathcal{G}_t$.
- Let  \begin{align}  &\sigma: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d
     \times d}, \\  &\mu: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d},
      \end{align}   be globally Lipschitz.
- Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution $S_t$ is adapted to the completed canonical filtration $(\bar{\mathcal{F}}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ of the driving Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$. Consequently, it suffices to show that $\bar{\mathcal{F}}_{t}$ is independent from $\mathcal{G}_0$ for all $t \geq 0$.

The admissibility of the filtration $(\mathcal{G}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ implies that $$(B_{t_n}-B_{t_{n-1}},\ldots,B_{t_1}-B_0)$$ is independent from $\mathcal{G}_0$ for any $0<t_1<\ldots<t_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since sets of the form $$\bigcap_{j=1}^n \{B_{t_j}-B_{t_{j-1}} \in A_j\}$$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $A_j$ measurable and $0=:t_0<t_1<\ldots < t_n \leq t$, generate the canonical filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$, this implies that $\mathcal{F}_t$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}_0$. Finally, we remark that adding (subsets of) nullsets doesn't destroy independence, and therefore $\bar{\mathcal{F}}_t$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}_0$.

Comment: saz: Does this work when the starting time is greater than zero? In this case, those sets do not generate $\mathcal{F}_t$.

Comment: @jpv Sorry, I don't get your question. What do you mean by "starting time greater than zero" (resp. by "starting time")?

Comment: If you are looking for a solution in the interval $[a,b]$ instead of $[0,T]$, the starting time is $a$. Sorry for the confusion. In this case, $X_t = \xi + \int_a^t \mu(X_s) ds + \int_a^t \sigma(X_s) dB_s$ and $a \leq t \leq b$.

Comment: @jpv I see. Why do you think that it makes that much of a difference? If you define $$\tilde{S}_t := \begin{cases} 0, & t<a, \\ S_t , & t \in [a,b] \end{cases}$$ then $\tilde{S}_t$ is adapted to $(\bar{\mathcal{F}}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and you can apply the reasoning from my answer (for $\tilde{S}$ instead of $S$). Alternatively, you can consider the restarted Brownian motion $W_t := B_{t+a}-B_a$ and trace everything back to the case that the starting time is zero.

Comment: The random variables $B_1, B_2,...$ will not generate the same sigma algebra as $B_1-B_a,B_2-B_1,...$, since $B_a\neq 0$. Therefore, we don't know if independence w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_a$ is valid. If we use the difference of Brownian motion, are we looking at weak solutions?

Comment: @jpv No, the notion of solution doesn't change. If you follow the first suggestion from my comment everything should work fine (and you don't need to change the driving Brownian motion)

Comment: $\mathcal{G}_a$ is independent of $(B_{t_n}-B_{t_{n-1}},\cdots,B_{t_1}-B_a)$ by definition. $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(B_s | a \leq s \leq t)$ does not equal the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the intersections in your answer, since the first term in the intersection would be $B_{t_1}-B_a$.  I want to show independence w.r.t. $\mathcal{G}_a$ and not $\mathcal{G}_0$. I may have a made a mistake in my argument though.

Comment: @jpv I see, I thought you were talking about $\mathcal{G}_0$. In that case you should try the second approach which I suggested in my earlier comment, i.e. introduce a new driving Brownian motion $W_t := B_{t+a}-B_a$, rewrite your SDE and then use a similar reasoning as in my answer. It should go through, I think. If you have further quesitons on this, it might be better to open a new question (... which would also avoid misunderstandings, as the recent one about $\mathcal{G}_0$ vs. $\mathcal{G}_a$).

Comment: Thanks. I got it.